# The website "gets deploys" or "get deploys" automatically everyday morning

Tags: grammar

Not a native speaker...

Which one is correct?

The website "gets deploys" or "get deploys" automatically everyday morning.

Or does it the sentence even make senses?

Comment: You should try this question on ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. _Deploy_ is a verb, not a noun; it can't be pluralized with -s, it can't be the object of _get_, and it can't be part of a construction with _get_.

Comment: Troops can *"get deployed"*, but I don't think websites generally can. (At least not automatically every morning. Is the website taken down automatically every night?)

Comment: @PeterShor It is not uncommon for overnight builds to be deployed in the morning.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182724/what-is-the-difference-between-deployment-and-release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. I believe you want

> The website is automatically deployed each morning.

I assume you want automatically to describe the method of deployment.